# How do I visualize the Meter and Counter metrics from Flink exposed to the JMX server on the VIsualVM?

Tags: java, apache-flink, jmx, visualvm

I configured Flink to expose metrics to JMXReporter as it is saying [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/monitoring/metrics.html#jmx-orgapacheflinkmetricsjmxjmxreporter). I have also configured a worker node to also expose its metrics to the master node as it is saying [here](https://www.prkz.de/blog/15-exporting-beam-metrics-on-flink-with-jmxreporter-and-prometheus-jmx-exporter). Below is the configuration of the `conf/flink-conf.yaml` file on the master and on the worker node. The Flink log files say that it is connected to the JMX server. Then I open the VisualVM and connect to my JMX server and I go to the MBeans tab. There I see the JobManager package. However, I don't find the counter and meter that I have created. I also installed the JConsole plugin. But when I go to the JConsole tab I see the message: `No JConsole plugin installed. To install a JConsole plugin click the Configure Plugins button and provide full path to the plugin file/directory`. And according to [this link](https://support.ptc.com/help/windchill/wc111_hc/whc_en/index.html#page/Windchill_Help_Center/WCSysAdminJMX_VisualVM_InstallVisualVMPlugIn.html), I need the `WtJmxPlugin.jar` file which I don't know where to find.

```
# Metrics Reporter on the MASTER node
metrics.reporter.jmx.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.jmx.JMXReporter
metrics.reporter.jmx.port: 8789-8790
metrics.reporter.jmx.interval: 30 SECONDS

# Metrics Reporter on the WORKER node
env.java.opts: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.56.1
```

I have a `RichMapFunction` which is exposing metrics.

```
public static class SensorTypeMapper
        extends RichMapFunction<MqttSensor, Tuple2<CompositeKeySensorType, MqttSensor>> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4080196110995184486L;

    private transient Counter counter;
    private transient Meter meter;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration config) {
        this.counter = getRuntimeContext().getMetricGroup().counter("counterSensorTypeMapper");

        com.codahale.metrics.Meter dropwizardMeter = new com.codahale.metrics.Meter();
        this.meter = getRuntimeContext().getMetricGroup().meter("meterSensorTypeMapper",
                new DropwizardMeterWrapper(dropwizardMeter));
    }

    @Override
    public Tuple2<CompositeKeySensorType, MqttSensor> map(MqttSensor value) throws Exception {
        this.meter.markEvent();
        this.counter.inc();
        // every sensor key: sensorId, sensorType, platformId, platformType, stationId
        // Integer sensorId = value.getKey().f0;
        String sensorType = value.getKey().f1;
        Integer platformId = value.getKey().f2;
        // String platformType = value.getKey().f3;
        Integer stationId = value.getKey().f4;
        CompositeKeySensorType compositeKey = new CompositeKeySensorType(stationId, platformId, sensorType);
        return Tuple2.of(compositeKey, value);
    }
}
```

[image]